# how to create private fold4 view in android

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout

I don't know how to make a fold screen.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_width="0dp"
```

If you use this, the entire screen will be filled in both general mobile phones and folds, and if you specify dp or use wrap_content, a blank space will be created.

I want to give a full screen on a normal mobile phone and a blank space on a fold. What should I do?

Here is an example photo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am temporarily implementing it using app:layout_constraintWidth_max. If there is a better way, I would appreciate it if you could provide it.